# How to test handler with if/then blocks in a unit test for an Angular.js service?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to testing and I need to test the handler in my Angular.js service (Using Jasmine and Mocha). This service checks the url and redirects to a state `main.loadbalancer.readonly` if the device number is readonly.

I am not sure how to test the handler, so since they are 2 if/then blocks with a function, I broke them up into their each `beforeEach(inject(function() {})`. Since they are going to be reused for several instances, I thought that would be best and then call them by `callHandler1(....)`, etc.

Right now, I am getting:

```
readonly service paste url with device 55, first load, will not go to main state
    â ReferenceError: callHandler1 is not defined
```

Am I doing this correctly?

---

Service:

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").run(function($rootScope, $state, DeviceVal) {
  return $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState) {
    var checkUrlDirectEdit, device;
    device = window.location.hash.split("/")[2];
    checkUrlDirectEdit = function() {
      return DeviceVal.previousDevice !== device && toState.name !== "main" && DeviceVal.lb.id === "undefined";
    };
    if (typeof DeviceVal.lb.id === "undefined" && toState.name !== "main" || checkUrlDirectEdit()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      DeviceVal.previousDevice = device;
      $state.transitionTo("main", {}, {
        location: false
      });
    }
    if (DeviceVal.readonly && toState.name !== "main.loadbalancer.readonly") {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {
        id: DeviceVal.lb.id
      }, {
        location: true,
        reload: true
      });
    }
    return window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
      return location.reload();
    });
  });
});
```

---

Test for service:

```
describe("readonly service", function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    return module("main");
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$state_, _DeviceVal_) {
    $rootScope = $rootScope;
    $state = _$state_;
    DeviceVal = _DeviceVal_;
    spyOn($state, "transitionTo");
    spyOn($rootScope, "$broadcast");
    event = jasmine.createSpyObj("event", ["preventDefault"]);
    event.preventDefault();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function() {
    checkUrlDirectEdit = function(DeviceVal, toState) {
      return DeviceVal.previousDevice !== device && toState.name !== "main" && DeviceVal.lb.id === "undefined";
    }
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function() {
    function callHandler1(DeviceVal, toState, device) {
      if (typeof DeviceVal.lb.id === "undefined" && toState.name !== "main" || checkUrlDirectEdit()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        DeviceVal.previousDevice = device;
        $state.transitionTo("main", {}, {
          location: false
        });
      }
    }
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function() {
    function callHandler2(DeviceVal, toState, device) {
      if (DeviceVal.readonly && toState.name !== "main.loadbalancer.readonly") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {
          id: DeviceVal.lb.id
        }, {
          location: true,
          reload: true
        });
      }
    }
  }));

  it("paste url with device 55, first load, will not go to main state", function() {
    device = 55;
    DeviceVal.lb.id = undefined;
    toState = { name: "not main" },
    DeviceVal.previousDevice = undefined;
    DeviceVal.readonly = false;
    callHandler1(DeviceVal, toState, device);
    callHandler2(DeviceVal, toState, device)
    expect(event.preventDefault).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("paste url with device 56, first load, will go to main state", function() {
    device = 56;
    Device.lb.id = undefined;
    toState = { name: "not main" },
    DeviceVal.previousDevice = undefined;
    DeviceVal.readonly = true;
    callHandler1(DeviceVal, toState, device);
    callHandler2(DeviceVal, toState, device)
    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith("main.loadbalancer.readonly",
      { id: 55 }, 
      { location: true, reload: true });
    });
});
```